# Android: Get activity context into array adapter class

Tags: android, android-animation, android-arrayadapter, android-context

I am trying to make a glass breaking effect on a tinder like cardstack. The cards are working fine but I am having trouble getting the activity contextinto the adapter so I can use the brokenview plugin.

I have my mainactivity, on that activity I show a fragment and on that fragment I display the cardstack.

On that card stack I want to show a glass breaking animation when a user clicks a low rating button using this library:

https://github.com/zhanyongsheng/BrokenView

So in my adapter  getview I set the context for the broken view with the context
with this line:

```
mBrokenView = BrokenView.add2Window((MainActivity)this.getContext());
```

But when I run click on the button I am getting this error:

```
ClassCastException: com.mysampleapp.Application cannot be cast to com.mysampleapp.MainActivity
```

Thank you for your help.

Full code below:

```
public class SongPreviewCardsDataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SongDatabaseMappingAdapter> {

    public SongPreviewCardsDataAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);

    }

    ImageButton oneStarRating;
    BrokenView mBrokenView;
    private BrokenTouchListener listener;

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, final View contentView, ViewGroup parent) {

       // Initialise Song Views
       final SongDatabaseMappingAdapter item = getItem(position);

       TextView songName = (TextView) (contentView.findViewById(R.id.songNameTextView));
       songName.setText(item.getSongTitle());

       // Initialise  Rating Buttons
        oneStarRating = (ImageButton) contentView.findViewById(R.id.ratingButton1);
        if (item.getOneStarRating()) {
            oneStarRating.setImageResource(R.drawable.starfull);

            mBrokenView = BrokenView.add2Window((MainActivity)this.getContext());
            listener = new BrokenTouchListener.Builder(mBrokenView).build();
            songName.setOnTouchListener(listener);

        }
```

Comment: A couple of questions here - why do you explicitly need the MainActivity context for the broken view? What are you passing as the context parameter of your adapter constructor?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean in the example ion github brokenView = BrokenView.add2Window(context); and then in the errors I was getting add2window(android.app.Activity) cannot be applied to android content context. So I assumed it needed the activity context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this instead:

```
mBrokenView = BrokenView.add2Window((MainActivity)(parent.getContext()));
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! What or how was I doing wrong?

Comment: When you're creating the `Adapter` you're most likely passing an `Application` `Context` as a constructor argument. What you need to bare in mind is that `Application` `Context` is not the same as `Activity` `Context`. You can't cast one to another just like so. The library you're using requires `Activity`, so you couldn't use the `Application` `Context` for that. `Views` have the `Activity` `Context` which you can obtain by `view.getContext()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
mBrokenView = BrokenView.add2Window(contentView.getContext());
```

Comment: Hi I already tried that before I asked the question. I get, Error:(84, 49) error: incompatible types: Context cannot be converted to Activity

Comment: Thanks @Eric unfortunateley that didn't work, same error. All good though Barteks response worked.